# Reference not found

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, appendices

When trying to reference to an appendix using `autoref` using the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Title of Section}
See \autoref{sec:appendix}.

\begin{appendices}
\section{Title of Appendix}
\label{appendix}
Contents of Appendix.
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The reference is not found, as shown here:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Figure references doesn't work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37100/figure-references-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
\label{sec:appendix}
```

instead of

```
\label{appendix}
```

i.e., the label has to be identical to the reference you use with `\autoref`.

Comment: Ouch... True, that's right, and very much shame on me for posting this question :-S

Comment: @vstrien: If this solves your problem consider marking the answer as a solution.

Comment: Of course I will - but yesterday I couldn't mark it yet  as I had to wait for 5 minutes (and 5 minutes later I wasn't online anymore :-))