# Figure references doesn't work

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm writing a document with some figures, each one has one label, and I'm using references. Every figure used appear at the list of figures, but not when referencing from text. When I do that, it prints "...like in Figure ??".

An example is:

```
GPS coordinates look like in Figure~\ref{fig:coord}.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{/img/coord.png}
    \caption{GPS coordinates representation}
    \label{coord}
\end{figure}
```

Where is the problem here?

Comment: Some feedback would be kind.

Answer (score 14):

Your label is `coord` but you reference via `fig:coord`. Both must be the same.

Moreover it is always a good practice to provide an minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
GPS coordinates look like in Figure~\ref{fig:coord}.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
  %  \includegraphics{/img/coord.png}
    \caption{GPS coordinates representation}
    \label{fig:coord}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```